# Prevent django send_mail timimg attack

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, timing-attack

I have different REST-API views where I either send a mail (if an account exists) or do not send a mail.
For example, the user can input the email in the forgot-password form and a mail is sent if the account exists.

I am using `from django.core.mail import send_mail` to send the mail.

The problem is, that this takes some time, and so requests for valid emails are generally longer than requests for non-exiting emails.
This allows an attacker to compare the request times to find out if an account exists or not.

Is there any way that I can call `send_mail()` without sending the mail?
Or what would be the fix to make request times equally long for both cases?

Note: I could check how long send_mail() needs on average and wait this time if I do not send the mail. As the app runs on different servers with different configs, this can not be generally done in my case. I would rather not store the average execution time per server in a database to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common practice to use [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/) for tasks that require some time to be finished. Celery will run a task in a separate thread and a user doesn't need to wait while it is finished. In your specific case what will happen if you use celery:

1. You send a task `send_mail` to celery and immediately return a successful response to a user.
2. Celery receives a task and runs it in a separate thread.

In this way, the response time for both cases will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

So this is something similar to an issue I had, and my solution was actually to always send the email, but the email reads something like `You tried to reset your password, but this email isn't registered to an account with us.` if they don't have an account.

From a user's perspective, it can be annoying to have to wait for an email that may or may not arrive, and spend time checking spam/junk etc. Telling them they don't have an account with that email address is quicker and cleaner for them.

We saw a big drop in users enquiring with us about why they hadn't received a PW reset email.

(Sorry for not actually answering the question, I dislike it when people do this on SO but since I experienced the same issue, I thought I'd weigh in.)